# retrieving similar items in query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I would like to retrieve similar items:

```
$formatsArray = $_POST['formats'];
$topicsArray = $_POST['topics'];


// Converting the array into individual strings
$formats = implode("','", $formatsArray);
$topics = implode("','", $topicsArray);

$resources = "select * from resources where
              format IN ('".$formats."')
               AND topic IN ('".$topics."')";
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to integrate the %% within the query. Because let's say topic is `Idea Generation`, and the mysql table is the `Idea Generation,Customer Development` then it will not match.

Comment: I din't understand your question. Also I see an error because you have written AND after where clause

Comment: the and was a small typo. in other words i want to retrieve items in format or topic that are either identical or similar. right now it only check if its identicla

Comment: @user3907211 did you try to remove single quotes ?

Comment: An example with some sample data please.
If you are trying to implement a logical or it can be done using 'or' / 'union' operator.

Comment: @PrudhviKonda what's wrong with having an `AND` in a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: AND will have to satisfy both the the conditions specified which means it will fetch records only if format column value contains one of the values of $formats and topic column value contains one of the values of $topic.

Answer (score 0):

While there might be a better way to do this, this should work:

```
$formats = implode("% OR format LIKE %", $formatsArray);
$topics = implode("% OR topic LIKE %", $topicsArray);

$query = "SELECT * from resources WHERE (format LIKE %" . $formats . "%) AND (topic LIKE %" . $topics ."%)"
```

This seems kind of like a hack but should work properly for your case.

Answer (score 0):

With your current DB scheme, read up on `FULL-TEXT` indexing in MySQL, as that's likely what you're looking for. The `LIKE` keyword in SQL is only really applicable if you're searching for singleton names. `LIKE` treats `%` as a "wildcard" and returns any row with the words before or after the `%` sign.

However, it seems you're DB schema is incorrect anyways. You should be normalizing your data in this case, do NOT store topics names in one column. Do something like this:

```
Table:resource
resource_id Primary Key Auto_increment, columnA, columnB

Table: format
resource_id int(11), format_name VARCHAR(150)

Table: topic
resource_id int(11), format_name VARCHAR(15)
```

This way, if you have some resource with the topics 'Idea Generation,Customer Development', you would insert two rows into `topics` and the connecting `resource_id` to tie them together.

This way, if you want to search for resources with the formats or topics in some array, you would do

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT t1.resource_id FROM resources as t1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT resource_id, format_name
    FROM format
) as t2 
ON t2.resource_id = t1.resource_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT resource_id, topic_name
    FROM topic
) as t3
ON t3.resource_id = t1.resource_id";

foreach ($formats as $format) {
    $sql .= "t2.format_name = '$format' OR"
}
$sql = trim($sql, ' OR');
$sql .= " AND ";
foreach ($topics as $topic) {
    $sql .= "t3.topic_name = '$topic' OR"
}
$sql = trim($sql, ' OR');
//Run the query
?>
```

This query should return all resource rows with formats or topics in the specified arrays you give `imploded` with. The query however, returns duplicate rows, so you should filter that out by modifying the `JOINS` and the query.